# How do i run 'tagged' scenarios with Cucumber tags in WebdriverIO

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io

Hi _ if anyone can help here- I am trying to run a specific scenario by using Cucumber tags- this is the expression i am using to run the tests built with Webdriver- Cucumber framework-

npx wdio run wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@Tag

When I use the above, nothing happens - i have defined the tag - '@Tag' at the feature level- so am expecting that all the scenarios within the feature file will get executed, however when i run the above command- nothing happens. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run only specific tests you can mark your features with tags.
These tags will be placed before each feature like so:

```
@sanity
Feature: checking for sanity test

Scenario:
 Given
 When:
 Then:
```

To run only the tests with specific tag(s) use the --cucumberOpts.tagExpression= parameter
like:

```
wdio -- --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@sanity'


wdio -- --cucumberOpts.tagExpression='@sanity or @AnotherTag'
```

Could not exactly predict issue you facing with the info you provided. I would suggest to have a look on the cucumber tag documentation and webderiverio testsuite implementation documentation.

[cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions)

[webdriverio](https://webdriver.io/docs/organizingsuites.html)

I hope it helps, Happy Learning !!

Comment: Heenu Pathak - Thank you!

Comment: Hey Mitali, can you please vote/accept the answer if its helpful to you :)

Answer (score 3):

I got it working having in package.json
`"scripts": { "test": "wdio ./wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression" }`

and running the test using
`npm run test "@Tag"`

Answer (score 1):

use as below
"test-imagesave": "wdio run 'config/wdio.conf.ts' --cucumberOpts.tagExpression '@tag'",

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

```
@abc
Scenario:…
```

Package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "wdio wdio.conf.js --cucumberOpts.tagExpression=",
    },
```

Note = at the end

Run it:

Cmd:

```
npm test '@abc'
```

**Second Solution:**

```
@abc
Scenario:…
```

Wdio.conf.js:

```
 cucumberOpts: {
      requireModule: [
        [
           …
        ],
      ],
      require: [
       …
      ],
…
      tagExpression: '@abc',
      …
    },
```

cmd:

```
npm test
```

**Third Solution:**

```
@abc
Scenario:…
```

Wdio.conf.js:

```
 cucumberOpts: {
      requireModule: [
        [
           …
        ],
      ],
      require: [
       …
      ],
…
      tagExpression: process.env.tag,
      …
    },
```

.env file:

```
tag = '@abc'
```

cmd:

```
npm test
```